# Disable quick-search animation in GTK3 File Chooser

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome3, gtk

Every time I do a quick-search by typing letters into the default file browser dialog of GTK3 applications, it will animate to a search hit if there's any. This wasn't in GTK2 File Chooser and is really annoying.

I would like to completely **disable all animations in GTK3 File Chooser**.

I have libgtk-3.0 **3.14.5** on Devuan Jessie **1.0.0**.

Your help is appreciated.